# Better to map helper functions or parent function?

Tags: python, optimization

I want to map a multi-step function onto a set of arrays. The multi-step (parent) function is composed of several helper functions. Currently, I am using map(parentFunction, argArrays**). The parent function and the helper functions all take in individual floats. Would it be more computationally efficient to instead make the parent function take in the arrays, and use map(helperFunction_i, someArgArrays**)?

I'm struggling here because I don't fully understand what's going on under the hood here. And while a fractionally small speed increase may not matter, an order of magnitude speed increase may matter because the parent function here is going to be nested inside a monte carlo loop, that monte carlo loop as a whole may be called thousands of times for a high-level function evaluation of a model I'm building, and I expect to need thousands of those high-level function evaluations for my research purposes.

While I'd most appreciate a direct and unambiguous answer to my question if an unambiguous answer exists, I'd also appreciate any recommended readings that would help me to understand how to write efficient code in python.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information to say anything for sure. A [MCVE] of at least one of the proposed implementations would be necessary to give useful responses, some idea of what libraries are in use, etc. As is, the answer could go any which way given different assumptions.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to say that. I was hoping that the answer would be sufficiently general that no further details would be needed. Since that's not the case, it seems that understanding the answer would take a deeper dive than I'm willing to commit to at the moment. I'll probably leave it as is for now and come back to the issue later if I need to refactor for more speed.